# Web API 2.0 Routing not working properly when deployed to godaddy

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting very strange routing behaviour issue in `Asp.net` Web API 2.0. When I am running my API in localhost it works fine with URL api/{controller} but now I have deployed this web API to GoDaddy shared server at that time it is working with api/api/{controller}. It is working when I use "api" keyword two times. If I use api/{controller} it gives me

> 404 error.(resource not found).

Can someone please help me to identify this strange behaviour?
In webapi.config.cs file default route is register.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and On Every controller I have used RoutePrefix as below

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class Testontroller : ApiController
{

}
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Post your Code. Cannot tell without looking at the code

Comment: For the code point of view I have used normal thing that used in web api.

In webAPi.config files Default route is register.

Comment: Post the code here

Comment: Try removing the api/ from routeprefix

Comment: yes Akshay that will surely work but main thing is need to find route cause that why it is working on api prefix on local and not working on server..

Comment: You are confusing convention based routing and attribute based routing. Use either of both to get your desired output

Comment: As you mentioned I have commented routing from webapiconfig.cs but still same issue is there main thing is that I have one other api also deployed on same server and it is working fine.Only this api has this routing issue.My assumption that it is something with godaddy server because on local it works perfectly,...I can't check for server much because it is shared hosting..